# Reading .fods file throwing NotImplementedError

Tags: python, pyexcel

I want to open, read and modify a `.fods` file using `pyexcel_ods`:

```
from pyexcel_ods import get_data

codebook_fods = get_data("myfile.fods")
```

But I'm getting just a `NotImplementedError` here.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: if your file is really an ods file, please rename it as "myfile.ods".

Comment: While there currently doesn't seem to be any Python package for this file format, it should be a plain XML file, so you could try parsing it yourself using the XML facilities that come with Python, or a package like `lxml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documentation regarding this package saying it support the `.fods` file extention. It is probably, as the error means, not implemented yet.

You can read more about it [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel-ods/).

As of what I know, there is no python implementation as of yet for the file extension you are trying to open.